# How to sum this table's column's values onchange?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I 'm not sure how to update the row total as each of these values change.I'm getting `$ is not defined"`, obviously because I still haven't learned it and I could use some help.

```js
function sum_row_qty(el) {
  let rowTotal = 0
  let parent = $(el).closest('tr')
  parent.find('.size_qty').each(function() {
    rowTotal += $('.size_qty').val();
  })
  console.log(rowTotal)
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="0" onchange='sum_row_qty(this)'></td>
  <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="17" onchange='sum_row_qty(this)'></td>
  <td class="total">0.00</td>
</tr>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zrxpfLnv/15/#&togetherjs=j4nmUawrMF)
Thank you!

Comment: the error `$ is not defined` is usually when you don't have jquery library included in your project and `$('.size_qty')` is a jquery element. If you are working with pure js, then that code won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options to fix this. Make sure you have included jquery to the page. Another option is simply use pure JS too as it's not that complicated and doesn't require jquery.

You will see similar code as the jquery with the addition of parseFloat, that way it converts the input to a float instead of a string.

```js
function sum_row_qty(el) {
  let rowTotal = 0
  let parent = el.closest("tr")
  parent.querySelectorAll('.size_qty').forEach(function(e){
    rowTotal += parseFloat(e.value)
  })
  console.log(rowTotal)
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="0" onchange='sum_row_qty(this)'></td>
  <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="17" onchange='sum_row_qty(this)'></td>
  <td class="total">0.00</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After hours looking at code and being a beginner, everything shimmers in front of me.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it like this with pure js, no jquery needed

```
<tr>
  <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value=0 onchange='sum_row_qty(this)'></td>
  <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value=17 onchange='sum_row_qty(this)'></td>
  <td class="total">0.00</td>
</tr>
```

use `getElementsByClassName` then run a loop since you have multiple elements with the same class

```
function sum_row_qty() {
  let rowTotal = 0
  const td = document.getElementsByClassName("size_qty");
  for (let i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
    rowTotal += parseFloat(td[i].value);
  }
  console.log(rowTotal)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Easy to assimilate. Had picked another choice, which came in first, though. Thank you!

Comment: This assume that OP wants every size_qty added together, not just the ones in the same table row.

Comment: well the classes `size_qty` come from the inputs, not the `td` after all,, if he has more inputs in other <tr> he can just give them another class